# Please help me with the following proof on Borel σ-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Please help me with the following proof on Borel $\sigma$-algebra
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})=\sigma(\{(a,b)\times(c,d); a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}\})$$
show $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$, where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
$$
\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})=\sigma(\{A\times B\,:\,A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}),\,B\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\})
$$
Now show both inclusions.

---

To show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\times\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$, we could the use the following result:

Let $(X,\mathcal{E})$ and $(Y,\mathcal{F})$ be measurable spaces. Then the product sigma-algebra is by definition given by
$$
\mathcal{E}\otimes\mathcal{F}=\sigma(\{A\times B: A\in\mathcal{E},\,B\in\mathcal{F}\}).
$$

> Suppose $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ are generators for the two sigma-algebras $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$, i.e. $\sigma(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{E}$ and $\sigma(\mathcal{D})=\mathcal{F}$ and assume that there exists sequencec $(C_n)$ and $(D_n)$ of sets from $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ respectively such that
>   $$
> X=\bigcup_n C_n\quad\text{and}\quad Y=\bigcup_nD_n.
> $$
>   Then
>   $$
> \mathcal{E}\otimes \mathcal{F}=\sigma(\left\{A\times B:A\in\mathcal{C},\,B\in\mathcal{D}\right\}).
> $$

Now choose $\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{D}$ according to your setup.

Comment: To show $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}) \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,  let $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})= \sigma(\{(a,b); a,b \in \mathbb{R} \})$ and $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})= \sigma(\{(c,d); c,d \in \mathbb{R} \})$. Then $(a,b)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $(c,d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ so $(a,b)\times(c,d)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Therefore  $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^2}) \subset \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Am I right? Can u please give me some hints on the other direction? Thanks!

Comment: @NZhang: Yes that's correct. For the other direction see the edit.