# $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^{m+n})=\mathcal B(\mathbb R^m) \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to prove the equality $$\mathcal B(\mathbb R^{m+n})=\mathcal B(\mathbb R^m) \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n),$$where $\mathcal B(\mathbb R^i)$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^i$.

I think I could show one inclusion:

Let $I \subset \mathbb R^{m+n}$ be an interval, then $I=I_s \times I_t$ where $I_s \in \mathbb R^m$, $I_t \subset \mathbb R^n$ are intervals. This means $I \subset \mathcal B(\mathbb R^m) \times \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n) \subset \mathcal B(\mathbb R^m) \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$. From here it follows $$\mathcal B(\mathbb R^{m+n}) \subset \mathcal B(\mathbb R^m) \otimes \mathcal B(\mathbb R^n)$$

I don't know how to show the other inclusion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you can infer your question from [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/337096/please-help-me-with-the-following-proof-on-borel-%CF%83-algebra) where the case $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is treated. Stefan Hansen answer is more general and should be applicable here I think.